# Tangent Points for Common Tangents between Two Ellipses (Ellipses described with rotation and translation coefficients)

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

The Problem:

Looking for the tangency points (where the lines would touch) between 2 ellipses (already rotated and translated). I have found generalized equations for standard ellipses but don't know how to adapt them. The ellipses may or may not overlap as well. I'm basically pulling the equation from a cad system and generating the tangent lines automatically.

Example of the information I have:

109.41x^2 + -278.93xy + 317.56y^2 + -33.04x + 48.67y = -1.57

1341.05x^2 + -868.64xy + 647.25y^2 + 6.06x + 12.59y = 0.89

[2 Ellipses that I believe correspond to the equations above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCZ5F.png)

The coefficients on the equations above have been rounded to 2 decimal places.

My background is mainly in programming, so a simplistic explanation would be wonderful as I need to "convert" the math/logic to code.

Thank you!!

Comment: By +- do you mean only $-$ or $\pm$?

Comment: Yes, its adding a negative number. Its just the way to equation is given by the CAD software.

Comment: You can convert this to the equivalent problem of finding the intersections of two conics by considering the duals to these ellipses.